# How do I put delay/sleep between executing two external programs using pascal?

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

I have code like:

```
begin
    RunProgram:=TProcess.Create(nil);
    RunProgram.Commandline:='calc.exe';
    RunProgram.Execute;
    RunProgram.Commandline:='notepad.exe';
    RunProgram.Execute;
    RunProgram.Free;
end.
```

and I would like to put a sleep or delay after executing calc.exe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had the right idea - it's `Sleep`.

```
begin
  RunProgram:=TProcess.Create(nil);
  RunProgram.Commandline:='calc.exe';
  RunProgram.Execute;
  Sleep(1000);             // Adds a 1 second delay
  RunProgram.Commandline:='notepad.exe';
  RunProgram.Execute;
  RunProgram.Free;
end.
```

You may need to add the `Windows` unit (or possibly a different one - I'm not familiar with FreePascal's unit arrangement) to your `uses` clause to be able to compile the `Sleep` function.